# Magento Custom options in grouped products page. Price not reflecting on selection

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I had a customized grouped product page in a magento store. I can able to put custom option values in that grouped product page by simply editing grouped.phtml file with this code.

```
foreach($product->getOptions() as $o):
  $values = $o->getValues();
```

I can able to publish custom option title and its value using this code;

```
echo $v->getData('title');
echo ('+').$v->getData('price');
```

But the problem is i can't able to reflect the price on custom option selection.

When i go through the view.phtml file, i can able to see that a function is calling on custom option fields so that price is reflecting.

So i rewrite my custom options select box code like this

```
<select name="sel_<?php echo $_item->getId()?>" id="sel_<?php echo $_item->getId()?>" class=" product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
      <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
  <?php  foreach ($values as $v):?>
      <option value="<?php echo $v->getData('title');echo ('+').$v->getData('price');?>">
        <?php echo $v->getData('title');echo ('+').$v->getData('price');?>
      </option>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Here I had called an onchange function opConfig.reloadPrice() in select box. But still price is not changing. What will be the possible issues?